# iOS AWS Appsync Fetch callback never called

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-ios

Hello I have a app that uses AWS AppSync as the backend.
and have an issue that appears randomly on multiple devices, that the fetch requests callback never called and the app ui is blocked by an activity indicator that should be hidden by the callback.

I am using the latest version of AppSync  `3.0.0` and the latest version of AWSMobileClient `2.12.7` and the issue remain the same on multiple devices with iOS `12.x.x` and earlier versions.

I have a network test in the app to insure that It can reach the internet, and It succeeds.

I tried to search for similar issue on github, but I mostly notice that the majority of issues are closed after a while for low interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a subscription enabled for the AppSync endpoint? If you are still facing the issue please raise an issue [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios/issues/new?template=bug_report.md).